# How to handle "input is not focusable" in javascript form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this control

```html
<div class="conico">
  <input class="form-control" readonly id="fileName"/>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" style="display:none;" required="xxx" id="fileSelect"/>
  <label for="xxx" class="ico">
    <img src="/images/icocamera.svg">
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to fill a text box with the name of a file. In my code above, I have an icon for every file. When an icon is pressed, the corresponding file name should populate the input.

This works fine, however, when the user doesn't select a file, then submits they get an error:

> input is not focusable

How can I handle this error with a custom javascript function?

Comment: Your file input is hidden, it can not be focused when there is an error. You can write your own validation script.

Answer (score 0):

fileName needs `required = true`, not the file selector.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  if ( $( "#fileName" ).val() ) {
    return;
  }
 
  console.log('not valid')
  event.preventDefault();
} );
```

Comment: `fileName` is `readonly` it doesn't make sense to make it `required`.

Comment: He has it `readonly` because it should only be filled as the result of a click on an icon, the user should not be allowed to type their own input. It needs to be required so the form object knows if it doesn't have a value, to not submit the form.